# Retrieving Parse Images Are Out of Order Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, parse-platform

I am writing an application in Swift that uses Parse for its backend. The user can post images to parse and they are displayed in a collectionView when the user logs in.

The new problem I am having is when retrieving all of my images from parse for the current user, the images are displayed all out of order. Actually, just about every time the images are retrieved they are in a slightly different order. I tried looking at other posts where people had this problem but they didn't seem to do the trick.

Here is my code to retrieve all image posts by a user (the current user):

```
func retrieveAllImagesForUserId(userId:String){
    self.arrayOfUserPosts.removeAll()
    let query = PFQuery(className: "ImagePost")
    query.whereKey("UserId", equalTo: userId)
    query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (object:[PFObject]?, error:NSError?) -> Void in

        if ( error != nil ){
            print(error?.localizedDescription, error?.userInfo)
        } else {

            for temp: PFObject in object! {
                let username:    String       = temp["Username"] as! String
                let userId:      String       = temp["UserId"] as! String
                let description: String       = temp["ImageDescription"] as! String
                let imageId:     String       = temp.objectId!
                let file:        PFFile       = temp["Image"] as! PFFile

                file.getDataInBackgroundWithBlock {
                    (imageData: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in

                    if error == nil {
                        if let imageData       = imageData {
                            let retrievedImage = UIImage(data: imageData)

                            self.imagePost = ImagePost.init(
                                image: retrievedImage!,
                                userId: userId,
                                imageId: imageId,
                                description: description,
                                username: username)
                            self.arrayOfUserPosts.append(self.imagePost!)
                            NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("retrievedPost", object: nil)
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The first thing i did was remove all objects to avoid any possible duplications to occur, maybe from a previous user who was logged on to the same device or anything like that.

For every image posted, i am also posting a column which has the users objectId whom posted that image. This way, i can query where said key is equal to the current users objectId.

I am doing an additional query to orderByDescending("createdAt") so the new images will be displayed at the top of my collection view.

My ImagePost class is an extremely simple class that is used for populating the area with objects, it looks like this:

class ImagePost {
    var postedImage: UIImage?
    var userId:      String?
    var imageId:     String?
    var description: String?
    var username:    String?

```
init(image:UIImage, userId:String, imageId:String, description: String, username: String ) {
    self.postedImage = image
    self.userId      = userId
    self.imageId     = imageId
    self.description = description
    self.username    = username
}
```

}

When the data is retrieved, i append the new ImagePost object to my array, which is the array i used to populate my collectionView and send a notification to reload the collection view.

I just really don't understand why I am having this problem so all of a sudden where the images are being retrieved in almost any order they choose. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

If you know the solution in objective-c but not swift that will also be helpful.

Thank you,
Rob

Comment: The reason is because of concurrency, not emptying the array. Every time you retrieve a new image and then subsequently attempt to download that image, the images themselves finish downloading out of order because those download functions are asynchronous too.

Comment: @pbush25 hmmm...interesting. I understand they are both asynchronous methods, but calling both of these methods seem necessary in this situation. what would you recommend in this situation?

Comment: This might seem a bit off topic, but can you specify what this line does NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName("retrievedPost", object: nil) ? Also why are you executing this line in a loop?

Comment: A better question is...why are you attempting to download all of the images at the same time? You should be downloading images as the user scrolls the collectionView, otherwise you waste data and time.

Comment: @Varun that was a mistake it should be placed outside of the loop. It is a notification being sent to my Controller to reload the collection view data.

Comment: @DBoyer I figured there might be some sort of a delay in the time it may take for the image to be downloaded to when its actually displayed to the user. To be honest I'm not sure exactly how to  request the images only as it scrolls. The idea is similar to a persons profile on instagram, it seems like all of the users posts are retrieved all at once

Comment: @DBoyer actually on Instagram it does seem to download the images as you scroll. My mistake. Still not sure how to do that, but i fear even if i figure out of how to do that it may still be somehow retrieved out of the order i am specifying

Comment: Are you using a collection view?

Comment: @pbush25 Yes i am, the notification at the end, which i have moved to out side of the loop is for reloading the data of the collection view being populated with the data being retrieved

Comment: Well then why don't you just use a PFQueryCollectionViewController or the answer below is a rather fine explanation as well.

Comment: Retrieve all our your ImagePosts from Parse. Sort them by createdAt and store the response in an array. In cellForItemAtIndexPath: call file.getDataInBackground and in the callback set the imageView's image. Do not download the image prior to cellForItemAtIndexPath:.

Comment: @DBoyer wow i guess i shouldn't be too hard on myself but that makes way more sense than what i was trying to do. The images are retrieved quickly without a long running operation in the main thread, and more importantly, in order! Thank you very much sir!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had integrated something similar using Parse.

You don't need to fetch all the images at first. You can use a third party library `SDWebImageCache` for downloading the image when needed or caching.

Have the `postedImage` type as `PFFile` and assign the imageFile directly. No need of fetching the imageData.

Have another key called `updatedAt` in `ImagePost` class. No need of using predicate when querying the objects from `Parse`. Save the `updatedAt` time of `ImagePost` class. So now you can directly append the data to `arrayOfUserPosts`.

After completion of the loop, you can sort the array and assign it to `self.arrayOfUserPosts`.

Then in tableView's dataSource `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method, you can do something like,

```
[cell.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:file.url] placeholderImage:nil completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {
    // Any custom view initialisation if needed.
}
```

where imageView is your display view for image, file is the object of type PFFile which represent the image. This is a Objective-C code. Similar syntax for Swift.

Comment: So i got this to work the way you suggested and id like to thank you for the suggestion of using SDWebImage. I installed the cocoapod and tested it in a seperate project and everything works fine. However, it often says cant find module 'import SDWebImage' . And even though it shows an error near the import it builds and runs just fine and the error disappears. Just curious if you ever had this problem. Other than that it works beautifully!

Comment: You're welcome. No I didn't face this problem. It might be some xcode issue which it might be trying to link but couldn't until runtime.

Comment: I forgot to link my library with the SDWebImage framework. after doing that it got rid of the error appropriately.